# How do I stop Visual Studio Express SP1 install detecting old version that doesn't exist

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation

I haven't installed Visual Studio before on my computer. However when I try to install Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1 I get an error message

"Setup has detected that this computer does not meet the requirements to install this software. These requirements must be met before you can install Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition with SP1 - ENU"

Requirements and Software Prerequisites
Visual Studios 2008 Service Pack 1
An earlier version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has been detected on the system that must be updated to SP1 before installation can proceed. Please update all other versions of Visual Studio 2008 to SP1 by visiting Microsoft Update and then install Visual Studio 2008 Express SP1.

I'm not sure why I get this message since I have not installed VS2008 before. I've tried to run the VS2008 Patch Removal Tool but it says "Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack Preparation does not apply". I've applied all the patches from Microsoft Update but still get the same error. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Ugh, I have a similar problem.  All my VS2008 stuff installed has already been updated to SP1.  Yet I get the same exact error trying to install another componenet.  :-(

Answer (score 5):

please use the following url instruction help ....and get solution within mins...i had the same issue and resolved it in mins

http://www.openspan.com/Community/index.php/component/kb/article/why_do_i_get_an_error_installing_the_microsoft_visual_studio_2008_sp1_isolated_shell.html

Comment: This was the right answer, as far as I'm concerned. For posterity, the page tells you to change HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0\SP from "0" to "1". If using Windows 64 bit, the key is HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0

Answer (score 1):

"I have not installed VS2008 before"

Maybe you should install VS2008 before trying to install a service pack on it.

If there's a slipstreamed download (VS2008 with SP1) then that will be quickest to install.  I don't know if there's a slipstreamed version or not, but even if there is, it looks like you didn't download it.

"An earlier version of Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 has been detected on the system that must be updated to SP1 before installation can proceed."

Well that's because Microsoft detected that you have to update VS2008 to SP1 before you can update VS2008 to SP1.  Microsoft's detection logic is most famous in Microsoft Update, where Microsoft Update has to download an updater to the update of the updater before the updater updater update will start updating.  If you need a detective, you should rely on Sherlock Holmes or common sense, rather than Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a registry entry that was placed by the program or something else. Run a registry cleaner (after backing the registry up) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Look at install/uninstall app. mark windows updates and look for visual studio ...

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem while trying to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition with SP1"...

After many different tries, the solution was to remove the registry key named

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS]

Note that I did not have any Visual Studio installed prior doing this. I do not recommend doing this if you have one. And remember to always make a backup copy of the removed key.

The alternative method could be to try to change values of 'SP' and 'SPIndex' from 0 to 1 under the keys:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\9.0\VSR\1033]

But I did not tried this and do not really know which of this keys are needed/checked.